# Multiplatform OpenCL application

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu, multiplatform

I'm looking for technology to speed up computations in my application (C++, processing of measurement data).
OpenCL is seems a good solution.
But for different platforms (ATI GPU, NVidea GPU & Intel) there is a different libraries and different runtimes.

Can I create a single realization that would be correctly processing in NVidea GPU, ATI GPU and Intel? Or I need to create a different realization for each platform?

Can I do:

```
void ComputeIt();
```

or I need to create:

```
void ComputeItAMD();
void ComputeItIntel();
void ComputeItNVidea();
```

???

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, are you just trying to write code that will work on each platform, or are you trying to use all available platforms simultaneously?

Comment: I trying to write code that will work on each platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to write it once. That's the whole point of OpenCL; write once, run anywhere!

The libraries are for the Vendors' implementation of OpenCL. E.g. if you have an Amd card, download the AMD library, Nvidia card, download Nvidia's library etc...

Comment: Does that mean that I have ship all runtimes with my product and select at runtime which to use, depending on the host capabilities?